# Saving Matlab/Octave plots to pdf/png format from online IDE?

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot, octave

I'm currently using the Matlab/Octave online IDE at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_matlab_online.php and I'm trying to save a graph that I'm plotting to .pdf format. I've done the following:

```
- octave
- x = [ 1: 10 ]
- y = x
- plot(x,y)
- print -dpdf graph.pdf
```

I then refresh the the files and folders to the left, double click on the graph.pdf file and am always greeted with a black filled rectangle. I've then attempted to run the following:

```
- axis("off")
- print -dpdf graph2.pdf
```

And the graph appears to save to pdf correctly. However, without the axes. Could you please assist me in finding a solution?

P.S. I have already attempted `octave --force-gui` and `graphics_toolkit('gnu_toolkit')/graphics_toolkit('fltk')` with no luck.

Comment: After setting `axis("off")` wouldn't you expect the axes to not appear?

Comment: Yes, that is expected. However the goal is to have the entire graph appear with the axes included. A black filled rectangle is being returned each time I attempt to save a PDF of a graph which is useless. I'm only noting that setting the axes to "off" seems to fix the issue somewhat but not fully because I now have a graph with no axes to make sense of the data shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the site hosted, the only graphics toolkit available is gnuplot, which support in octave was mostly dropped several versions ago. 
[gnuplot has the bug you've described.](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44458) In the link, people got plotting working by rolling back to previous gnuplot versions.
Guess the only way of getting printing working on the site would be signalling about the issue to its administration.

Also, note that octave crudely depicts the copy of the plot in terminal window. That might suffice for correctness check of the plotting code itself.

Alternatively, you can save octave graphics objects with `hgsave` command, those then can be loaded in octave on another computer to obtain same plot as one that would be drawn there. (Although, at this point there might be no reason for using online interpreter then.)